# VCR not using cassette in rails system test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, vcr

In the following test:

```rb
require "application_system_test_case"

class ImportTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test "importing vacancy succeeds" do
    VCR.use_cassette("import_success", record: :all) do
      user = users(:role)
      sign_in(user)

      visit new_externals_path

      within "form.form" do
        fill_in "External ID", with: "57524"

        click_on "Import Vacancy"
      end

      # TODO: Check that the imported vacancy is displayed
    end
  end
end
```

If I turn on debug logging VCR outputs the following:

```
[Cassette: 'import_success'] Initialized HTTPInteractionList with request matchers [:method, :uri] and 0 interaction(s): {  }
[webmock] Identified request type (recordable) for [post https://url.com/oauth/idp]
[webmock] Handling request: [post https://url.com/oauth/token] (disabled: false)
[webmock] Identified request type (unhandled) for [post https://url.com/oauth/token]
```

Rails don't find a cassette and ask me to provide one which I simply cannot understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way to make this work is by adding the following:

```rb
setup do
  VCR.insert_cassette("path/#{@NAME}", record: :new_episodes)
end

teardown do
  VCR.eject_cassette
end
```

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for this one? I use `around { |example| VCR.use_casette("path/to/cassette", <options hash>, &example) }`. Slightly less verbose than your answer, but would still be great to be able to put it inline in the test itself.

Comment: Guess I could also mention that I only have this issue when Turbo is enabled. If I disable Turbo, then wrapping a section of the test works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with this too, but I found that the issue was that I wasn't waiting/expecting changes to the page, so VCR ejected the cassette immediately after I made the last UI interaction in the test and before the request that it triggered had time to complete.

I was using Turbo to handle that UI interaction, so I assume that could be related to why it didn't wait for the request to complete.